# I have tried for days to get the right htaccess mobile redirect coding

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have tested out hundreds of different codes, either they work and screw something else up, or they don't work at all.  This sounds lazy but I really have tried hundreds of combinations.

I have my main domain that I want redirected to my "mobile" sub domain (detecting mobile agent), and along with a folder of .html pages I have.  Both directories match up file name wise.

Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a website with information on how to redirect based on the browser's user-agent string:

http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-how-to-redirect-users-to-mobile-or-normal-web-site-based-on-device-using-mod_rewrite

Your .htaccess should look like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
# (You could add another [OR] to the second one and add in what you
#  had to check, but I believe most mobile devices should send at
#  least one of these headers)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^mobile\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\smredir=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile.jguffphotography.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**Make sure you update to the latest code above.**

I have updated all of the code above to reflect what is should look like.

Comment: that gives me "too many server redirects," it is redirecting from both places I wanted it to though.

Comment: Also, step 2 and 3 I don't even know what that is.. do I need apache?

Comment: my host is webhostingpad, I edit all my sites in there. Is that what you meant?  I've never used a 3rd party editor or anything.

Comment: Still says "too many server redirects." I copied it exactly, but made it say "http://mobile.jguffphotography.com" instead of "http://m.example.org"

Comment: @JGuff330 Try clearing your browser's cache and then close the browser, open it and try again.

Comment: Really? Wow maybe it's my phone.  Its an LG G2x it's not that old at all. I just tried using a different browser too, same thing.

Comment: @JGuff330 Look at the "Make sure" above in my answer.  That is the only thing left you need to change.

Comment: That works, but on the main page it doesn't load images, and one the other page it acts like I'm missing a stylesheet. I saw a similar problem like that earlier. So frustrating lol.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/20120704002525.png/ & http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/109/20120704002608.png/ screenshots   UPDATE: it worked in dolphin browser, but not the default.

Comment: @JGuff330 Change all relative URLs to point to the non-mobile site e.g. change all instances like this: `style.css` to `http://www.jguffphotography.com/style.css` in your HTML.

Comment: All the urls are in long form now already, except for the main (non mobile) page.  Everything shows without the .htaccess in place.  I have all the images on the jguffphotography and I link them from mobile subdomain.  Do I have to upload them to the subdomain images folder too?

Comment: Kind of like anti hotlinking. I just tried a tester, uploaded a pic to the subdomain images folder, and then linked it on the mobile index.. and it displayed fine.

Comment: @JGuff330 Good. You can upload a copy of all images to the mobile site and it should work then. Glad it got sorted out.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.  Thanks for taking so much time!

Comment: Ok weird. It's all working (finishing up), I didn't have to change the url to images/filenap.jpg, i left them the same (full url) and just had to upload the images to the sub domain sister folder.